# How to detect slow connection in ROKU Scene Graph?

Tags: roku, brightscript

The requirement says "Switch to low definition video when connection is slow"
I'm wondering is there anyway.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Normally the Roku player will handle this on its own either with a set of on demand URLs with varying bitrates specified, or a linear stream with an HLS manifest specifying the multiple bitrates the player can retrieve based on its own bandwidth detection.

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking the streamInfo field of the video node.
It is an associative array, which holds some info:

> measuredBItrate   (Integer)   The measured bitrate (bps) of the network when the stream was selected.
>
> streamBitrate (Integer)   The bitrate of the stream